# Regular expression to match a pattern inside awk command

Tags: regex, awk

I need to write a regular expression to match the following pattern :

```
fltr_desc_name
```

that is.. 
"fltr" followed by an underscore followed by any number of words separated by underscore.

for example: 
I need a regular expression to match the following :

```
fltr_desc_name
fltr_nameone_nametwo
fltr_level_name_desc
```

and I am using it inside an "if" statement in "awk":
for ex:

```
awk '/Transformation/ { if ($4=="Filter" && $5=="fltr_*") print $4,$5 }' filename
```

please help me in writing the regular expression and tell me how to use regular expression inside an "if" condition inside "awk" command. Thank you.

Comment: what you have tried so far!! and why regular expression. use string function for that

Comment: Hello :) ,
I am using the regex to find all lines whose tranformation field type is Filter, (ie $4, 4th field as given in file) and $5 is name of filter that shld b of the format "fltr_followedbyanywrdsseparatedbyunderscore". and so I was using the awk cmd as shown in the question, but i was unable to mactch the lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
awk '/Transformation/ && $4=="Filter" && match($5, /^fltr_[A-Za-z_]+/) { print $4,$5 }' filename
```

No need to use an `if` statement, you can just use multiple matching conditions as per above. `match` returns the match location of the regex `^fltr_[A-Za-z_]+` in `$5`, or 0 if there is none. 0 evaluates to false and anything else to true.

Comment: @Karthik The match() is unnecessary. Your main problem was just that you were using a string comparison operator (==) instead of an RE comparison operator (~). I'll post the real solution.

Comment: @EdMorton, nice - was looking for a regex operator in `man awk` but it wasn't listed among the other operators so I missed it and went for `match` instead. Thanks!

Comment: @EdMorton, Yup. Thank you. But I needed to use regular expressions say inside the "awk" command. i.e, $5=="fil_*".. "fil_*" was supposed to be a regex and I didnt know the syntax to include it under "awk" command. I believe "$5==fil_*" without the match() function, "fil_*" was considered as a string and not as a pattern. If i am wrong, please correct me coz I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: As i said the RE comparison operator is '~'. You also want to use /fil_*/, not "fil_*", so fil_* is treated as a RE constant and not as a string in an RE comparison. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Operators.

Answer (score 25):

Need to use tilde character `~/ /` in matching regular expressions in awk, i.e.

```
if ($5 ~ /fltr_*/)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
awk '/Transformation/ && $4=="Filter" && $5~/^fltr_[[:alpha:]_]+/ { print $4,$5 }' filename
```

Comment: +1 for using the locale-aware character class. For generality, I'd use `[:alnum:]` even though it wasn't stated.

Comment: The OP stated the string contained "words separated by underscore" and, in my head at least, **words** don't contain numbers but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: I can see that, particularly given the example `fltr_nameone_nametwo` but it's not a stretch to extend that to `fltr_name1_name2`

Comment: Yup, in case of just words, [:alnum:]. if numbers hv to be included along with words , then ill opt for [:alnum:]. Thanks for your suggestions guys. cheers

Answer (score 1):

`fltr_[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z]`

or if you want to match from string start to string end only:

`^fltr_[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z]$`

Comment: +1 for not ending with an underscore, even though it was not stated explicitly

Answer (score 0):

you could just use `fltr_\w+`

if you need a good program for writing and testing regex. try this one: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @selltheworld Thank you for your suggestion and also the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^fltr[_\d\w]+$
```

It will take all, you need.

Comment: OP wants awk, not perl. Additionally, `\w` includes `_` and `\d` already -- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Word-characters

Comment: @og Grand, Thanks for your answer. I will try your suggestion too :)